# elif checking how close to a random number a user set number is

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple program to test out the basics of Python I've been learning. I decided to do a simple tongue in cheek gambling script that checks a user entered number against a 1,100 random generated number. I want to multiply the users stake by a different amount depending on how close to the random number the user guessed, but cant seem to get it to check within a range using == or <= etc. Or at least cant work it out.

i.e, user stakes 10 on number 15.
if the random number is 20 it's within 5 of the users number so multiply the stake by 25.
if the random number is 25 its within 10 or less of the users number so multiply by 10 etc.

Here's what I've got, would love to hear any advice on this!

```
if random_number == int(playernumber):
              playerstake = int(playerstake) * 100
              print("\nCongratulations, you hit the JACKPOT and won £" + str(playerstake) + "!!!")
#+/- 1
       elif int(playernumber) == int(random_number) + 1:
              playerstake = int(playerstake) * 50
              print("\nCongratulations, you guessed within 1 of " + str(random_number) + " and won £" + str(playerstake) + "!")
       elif int(playernumber) == int(random_number) - 1:
              playerstake = int(playerstake) * 50
              print("\nCongratulations, you guessed within 1 of " + str(random_number) + " and won £" + str(playerstake) + "!")

#+/- 5
       elif int(playernumber) == int(random_number) + 5:
              playerstake = int(playerstake) * 20
              print("\nCongratulations, you guessed within 5 of " + str(random_number) + " and won £" + str(playerstake) + "!")
       elif int(playernumber) == int(random_number) - 5:
              playerstake = int(playerstake) * 20
              print("\nCongratulations, you guessed within 5 of " + str(random_number) + " and won £" + str(playerstake) + "!")
```

etcetc
I understand this currently doesn't work because I'm == random number + 1
so 12 would be 13.

Apologies if I've done something frowned upon here, this was my first script I tried to tackle and wanted to see the potential ways to have done this 'properly'. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: `abs(6 - 8) = 2`, this can be useful for cheking the distance of two numbers

Comment: In the future when posting question try using the correct indentation and naming convention, i.e. snake case and not snake case for playernumber and random_number.

Comment: @Caridorc thank you I'll have a look into this!

Comment: @Lucian my apologies, I'm very new to this and still haven't touched on a lot of things. I was just trying to blindly figure it out! Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, much simpler code:

```
dist = abs(guess - rand_num)

if dist == 0:
    multiplier = 100
elif dist <= 1:
    multiplier = 50
elif dist <= 5:
    multiplier = 20
elif dist <= 10:
    multiplier = 10
else:
    multiplier = 0
    
player_stake += player_stake * multiplier
if dist == 0:
    print("Congratulations you've won")
else:
    print("Congratulations you guessed {0} within {1} and won ${3}".format([multiplier, rand_num, player_stake])
```

Comment: Thank you for this, that does look a lot like what I'm aiming for. I just searched abs and this definitely seems like a better way around it! This was my first blind attempt at coding something so it's great to see much more efficient ways around it like this. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Glad to help. We were all beginners once. Do please get in the habit of marking responses as answers if they answered your question or up voting any responses you feel helped.

Comment: Have marked as answered but unfortunately cannot upvote yet, appreciate it though thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat yourself. You could replace your if clauses with a lookup table. With only 3 things, its a toss-up whether this is better, but generally, if the logic is the same within multiple conditional clauses, its good to pull that logic out into a single implementation. The lookup table lets you change the boundaries used for selection without touching the logic.

```
# assumes `diff`, `random_number` and `playerstake` defined at time of use
exact_text = f"Congratulations, you hit the JACKPOT and won £{playerstake}"
near_text = f"Congratulations, you guessed within {diff} of {random_number} and won £{playerstake}"

# lookup table: (diff, payout, text)
odds = [
    (0, 100, exact_text),
    (1, 50, near_text),
    (5, 20, near_text)
]

playernumber = int(playernumber)
playerstake = int(playerstake)
player_diff = abs(random_number - playernumber)

for diff, payout, text in odds:
    if player_diff <= diff:
        playerstake *= payout
        print(text)
        break
else:
    print(f"You were {player_diff} away from the random number")
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This is the first thing I've tried to code before so the process of identifying easier ways round is hard at the minute! I see what you've done with the lookup table, it really has condensed it down. I'll have a play around and clean it up. Thank you for the reply I appreciate it!